# Custom Layer not drawing using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have a Customer layer which inherits BaseCustomLayer.

I add it to my MapControl via addLayer but the function `public override void Draw(esriDrawPhase drawPhase, IDisplay Display, ITrackCancel trackCancel)` is never hit.

The Custom Layer appears checked in the TOC.

I think I must be missing some initialization one-liner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a minimalist custom layer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

namespace MapControlApplication1
{
    class CustLayer2: BaseCustomLayer
    {
        public override void Draw(esriDrawPhase drawPhase, IDisplay Display, ITrackCancel trackCancel)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("drawing {0} {1}", drawPhase,  Environment.TickCount);
        }
    }
}
```

I created a new Project and choosing C#>ArcGIS>Extending ArcObjects>Mapcontrol Application, then added a new menuitem on the menu of MainForm with this:

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CustLayer2 layer = new CustLayer2();
        layer.Name = "cust layer2";
        axMapControl1.AddLayer(layer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I run I see this output as I pan around the map:

```
drawing esriDPGeography 441416029
drawing esriDPGeography 441422207
drawing esriDPGeography 441433579
```

Comment: I had "dynamicMap.DynamicMapEnabled = true;" which was interferring with your example.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  For a custom layer to draw when the dynamicmap is enabled, I think you'll need to implement IDynamicLayer too.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000122000000